# greater than function does not work when 0 is inputted

Tags: javascript

I need to validate the user input where user can only enter the value not equal to but greater than 0 and smaller than stated value. My validation logic works if i provide certain object

```
{required:true, greaterThan: 1, smallerThan: 50}
```

Here, if i input the value 0, then it displays an error message saying, `value should be greater than 1` but if in case, i provide the following object instead

```
{required:true, greaterThan: 0, smallerThan: 50}
```

and I input the value 0 then it does not display an error message saying `value should be greater than 0`

Here is my validation logic

```
if (fieldValue.smallerThan && value && parseInt(value, 10) > fieldValue.smallerThan) {
    set(
        errors,
        key,
        `${fieldValue.label} should be smaller than ${fieldValue.smallerThan}`,
    )
    }
if (fieldValue.greaterThan && value && parseInt(value, 10) < fieldValue.greaterThan) {
    set(
        errors,
        key,
        `${fieldValue.label} should be greator than ${fieldValue.greaterThan}`,
    )
}
```

Comment: `&& value` won't pass: `0` is falsy

Comment: to check if `smallerThan` is a property in `fieldValue`, you can use _in_ like so: `smallerThan in fieldValue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 && any value
```

Will always result in `false` because `0` is considered as `falsy` value in javaScript

What You can do  is

`fieldValue.greaterThan >= 0 && ..`

Comment: is it like this? ``` if (
        fieldValue.greaterThan >=0 &&
        value >=0 &&
        parseInt(value, 10) < fieldValue.greaterThan
      ) ```

Comment: @Serenity yes if you want `greaterThan`  and `value` greater than or equal to `0` and `value` less than `greaterThan`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just checking for existence of the greater than property in the fieldValue, which seems to be what you're doing, you might also considering editing your two checks to be:

if (fieldValue.smallerThan !== undefined && ...)

and

if (fieldValue.greaterThan !== undefined && ...)

In general, relying on the truthiness or falsiness of values gets you into trouble, and it's better to be explicit about what you are checking for.

Answer (score 0):

always convert your inputs to an integer or float.

```
if(!(fieldValue.smallerThan < parseInt(value))){
  ...value must be smaller than 50
}

if(!(fieldValue.greaterThan > parseInt(value))){
  ...value must be greater than 0
}
```